# UWP: Images in GridView cause memory leaks

Tags: c#, xaml, memory-leaks, uwp, bitmapimage

I've developed an **UWP app** for managing forms. Each form can contain a lot of images. These **images raise memory leaks**, and I don't found any solution to fix this.

Currently all the datas are stored in a **SQLite database**, including the images, as **byte[]**.

The root object is a "***Car_Form***", which contains the "***Images***" in an **ObservableCollection**:

```
public class Car_Forms : BasePoco
{
    // form_id
    private int _form_id;
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull, AutoIncrement]
    public int form_id
    {
        get
        {   return _form_id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _form_id)
            {
                _form_id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => form_id);
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    // images
    private ObservableCollection<Images> _images;
    [Ignore]
    public ObservableCollection<Images> images
    {
        get
        { return _images; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _images)
            {
                _images = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => images);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "***Images***" object contains the reference to the "***Car_Form***", the **byte[]** that is stored in the SQLite database in the "***image1***" field, and the **BitmapImage** that is used for the display, in the "***image_display***" field:

```
public class Images : BasePoco
{
    // image_id
    private int _image_id;
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull, AutoIncrement]
    public int image_id
    {
        get
        { return _image_id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _image_id)
            {
                _image_id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => image_id);
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    // image1
    private byte[] _image1;
    [NotNull]
    public byte[] image1
    {
        get
        { return _image1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _image1)
            {
                _image1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => image1);
            }
        }
    }

    // form_id
    private int? _form_id;
    public int? form_id
    {
        get
        { return _form_id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _form_id)
            {
                _form_id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => form_id);
            }
        }
    }

    // bitmap_image
    private BitmapImage _bitmap_image;
    [Ignore]
    public BitmapImage bitmap_image
    {
        get
        { return _bitmap_image; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _bitmap_image)
            {
                _bitmap_image = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => bitmap_image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my XAML page, the "***Images***" are in displayed in a **GridView** like this:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CarForm.images, Mode=OneWay}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          Grid.Row="1">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Images">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" 
                    Background="White"
                    Padding="10"
                    Height="160" Width="225">
                <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
                       Source="{x:Bind image1, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter}}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The datas are loaded from the SQLite database in the **ViewModel**:

```
private Car_Forms _carForm;
public Car_Forms CarForm
{
    get { return _carForm; }
    //set { Set(ref _carForm, value); }
    set
    {
        this._carForm = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CarForm);
    }
}

private void LoadForm(Guid id)
{
    CarForm = RepositoryService.GetById<Car_Forms>(id);            
    var formImages = RepositoryService.Where<Images>(im => im.IsDeleted == false && im.form_id == CarForm.form_id);
    CarForm.images = new ObservableCollection<Images>(formImages);
    //...
}
```

Then, the the **BitmapImage** is loaded through the "***ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter***":

```
public class ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            var bImg = (byte[])value;
            if (bImg != null)
            {
                BitmapImage biImg = ByteArrayBitmapHelper.AsBitmapImage(bImg);
                return biImg;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static BitmapImage AsBitmapImage(this byte[] byteArray)
{
    if (byteArray != null)
    {
        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer()).GetResults(); 
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            stream.Seek(0);
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have also implemented a "***Cleanup()***" method on the **ViewModel**, where I "clean" all the objects that are used:

```
public override void Cleanup()
{
    //...
    CarForm.images.Clear();
    CarForm = null;
    base.Cleanup();
}
```

But when I launch the app, I can see that **all resources are not released**: each time that I open the same form and that I come back to the list, there are 30 Mo that are not released.

[image: Memory Leaks]

1. laucnh of the app: "Home" page
2. display of the form
3. back to the "Home" page
4. display of the form
5. back to the "Home" page
6. display of the form
7. display of the form
8. back to the "Home" page
9. display of the form

***=> Would you have any explanation? How could I optimize it?***

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because pages in UWP are not cached by default, so everytime you navigate to page, new instance of that page is created. You can set the `NavigationCacheMode` property of the page to `NavigationCacheMode.Required` so the pages will be cached and navigation will not be causing memory leaks.

Comment: I've tried to use the `NavigationCacheMode.Required` but it didn't work at all: each time I'm opening a Form, it's the same form that is reloaded. But if I always open the same form: there are no longer memory leaks.

Comment: For me setting NavigationCacheMode.Required fixed my problem